# Python 2.x vs 3.x imports, depending on where script is called/imported from

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

This is likely the ~1000th question on import differences between Python 2.x and 3.x, but for my specific problem/case I am still stuck after reading most of them. Consider this simple example:

*Directory structure:*

```
main.py
src/
    thermo.py
    constants.py
    __init__.py  # empty
```

*main.py:*

```
import src.thermo as thermo
thermo.calc_thermo()
```

*src/thermo.py:*

```
from constants import cp

def calc_thermo():
    print(2*cp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Just for testing `thermo.py`
    calc_thermo()
```

*src/constants.py:*

```
cp = 1234.
```

Now, there are two ways in which I want to use `thermo.py`; calling it directly from the `src/` subdirectory (for debugging/unit-testing/.. of this specific file), or as part of the entire program by importing it into `main.py`. With the example above this all works in Python 2.7, in Python3.x I can call `thermo.py` from the `src/` directory, but importing `thermo` from `main.py` fails on the import of `constants`.

There are many similar questions here on SO, most suggesting to fix this with relative imports, i.e. changing `thermo.py` from:

```
from constants import cp
```

to

```
from .constants import cp
```

Now it works if I call `main.py`, but I lose the ability to call `thermo.py` directly from the `src/` directory! How can this best be solved, i.e. creating the possibility to both import `thermo.py` from its parent directory (`main.py`), but also to keep the possibility to call `thermo.py` directly from `src/`?

Comment: My suggestion would be to always go with package level imports.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, can you clarify that? How would that work for my example?

Comment: Have you set `$PYTHONPATH` to anything?

Comment: @JohnZwinck; no. You mean adding the `src` directory to the `PYTHONPATH` to get rid of all the relative imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to include your `src` directory (its absolute path, of course) should make imports work from any directory.

This environment variable must be set prior to launching the Python interpreter.

Comment: I've seen that solution before, but that always looked like a *very* ugly hack to me. Is my use case that strange, or just a flawed design?

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` is not an ugly hack, it is the standard way to do this sort of thing in a development environment or anywhere you don't want to deploy a full-blown package into your Python installation's `site-packages` directory.  You can also use `sys.path` to do the same thing.